# ng-checked generating too many events

Tags: angular-material

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLpwWo

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="exists(item, selected)" ng-click="toggle(item, selected)">
```

Open the console and click a few times

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520097/when-exactly-is-ng-checked-called

Comment: That is a different issue.